# Condicionais e Fluxo de Controle (Codecademy Python 9/15)

Tags: python, controle-de-fluxo

Olá, estou realizando um exercicio do codecademy e tenho de resolver as seguintes condicionais:

- Iguale bool_one ao resultado de False or not True and True
- Iguale bool_two ao resultado de False and not True or True
- Iguale bool_three ao resultado de True and not (False or False)
- Iguale bool_four ao resultado de not not True or False and not True
- Iguale bool_five ao resultado de False or not (True and True)

Segue abaixo minhas respostas:

```
bool_one = False
bool_two = False
bool_three = True
bool_four = True
bool_five = False
```

Porém o validador do exercicio está indicando que uma ou mais respostas estão erradas.

Comment: qual a mensagem aparece quando voce tenta prosseguir?

Comment: Tenha certeza de ter um valor para cada um das 5 variaveis!

Answer (score 4):

O seu erro está no segundo item, que é esse:

- Iguale bool_two ao resultado de False and not True or True

Executando o código:

```
print False and not True or True
```

Você terá como resultado:

> True

Olhando na tabela de precedência em [Python Docs - Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) você verá que o `not` tem maior precedência dentre os operadores dessa expressão, e o `and` tem a segunda maior precedência, sendo ele executado antes do `or` porém depois do `not`. Portanto o compilador faz os seguintes cálculos:

- not True => False
- False and False => False
- False or True => True (resultado final)

Ao fazer um testo e dar precedência maior para o `or` pode-se ver que o resultado é `False`. Exemplo:

```
print False and not (True or True)
```

Resultado:

> False

Comment: Continuo obtendo o mesmo erro:

Tenha certeza de ter um valor para cada um das 5 variaveis!

Comment: E você tem certeza de que associou um valor para cada uma das 5 variáveis? Existe mais do seu código que você poderia estrar mostrando?

Comment: Não, apenas isso.

Comment: @RenoirDosReis eu fiz esse curso há algum tempo, voltando para ver como eu fiz vi que não há nada de errado com o seu código. Veja: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yiEor.png Ainda está tendo o erro?